# Custom ActionResult equivalent Model for all PartialViews

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, actionresult

I created following custom `ActionResult` which returns multiple partial views.

```
public class MultiplePartialViewsResult : ActionResult
{
    private const string Separator = "-";
    private PartialViewResult[] _partialViews;

    public MultiplePartialViewsResult(params PartialViewResult[] partialViews)
    {
        _partialViews = partialViews;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        foreach (var partialView in _partialViews)
        {
            partialView.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Output.Write(Separator);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I use it as follows:

```
return new MultiplePartialViewsResult(
             PartialView("~/Views/RowSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 1.0 }),
             PartialView("~/Views/ColumnSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 2.0 }));
```

But if I place breakpoint in `MultiplePartialViewsResult`'s constructor I see that model in both cases equals `2.0`. It overrides all models with the last model specified in a array.

 Try to create couple PartialViews in method and assign it to variable. Then you will notice they all share equivalent model.

Comment: Yes it is correct.If you are trying to return two `model`s to one view, create a `view model` that contains both of the models that you want to send, and make your view's model the new `ViewModel`

Comment: That is the point that I am trying to return to many views.Idea is based on this post where author indicates that models can be distinct.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: Have check last things? It says to use `view model` shared by both `partial view`.

Comment: "In the example, the two partial views use the same view model. This is not a limitation though. "

Comment: Yes .So In your example you have to use single `view model`

Comment: Why would I if an author states it is not obligatory. Apparently something under the cover acts in PartialView that it saves only last model used.

Comment: May be. You have to wait for better answer to judge this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize the **MultiplePartialViewsResult** object in the following manner with **new own** **ViewData** / **ViewData.Model** instances (works fine for me):

```
return new MultiplePartialViewsResult(
    //PartialView("~/Views/RowSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 1.0 }),
    //PartialView("~/Views/ColumnSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 2.0 })
    new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "~/Views/RowSumView.cshtml", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary() { Model = new List<double>() { 1.0 } } },
    new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "~/Views/ColumnSumView.cshtml", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary() { Model = new List<double>() { 2.0 } } }
);
```

**Custom Action Result:**

```
public class MultiplePartialViewsResult : ActionResult {
    private const string Separator = "-";
    private PartialViewResult[] _partialViews;

    public MultiplePartialViewsResult(params PartialViewResult[] partialViews) {
        _partialViews = partialViews;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        foreach(var partialView in _partialViews) {
            partialView.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Output.Write(Separator);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
public ActionResult FakeAction() {
    return new MultiplePartialViewsResult(
        //PartialView("~/Views/RowSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 1.0 }),
        //PartialView("~/Views/ColumnSumView.cshtml", new List<double>() { 2.0 })
        new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "~/Views/RowSumView.cshtml", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary() { Model = new List<double>() { 1.0 } } },
        new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "~/Views/ColumnSumView.cshtml", ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary() { Model = new List<double>() { 2.0 } } }
    );
}
```

**Views:**

**Index:**

```
@Html.Action("FakeAction")
```

**ColumnSumView.cshtml / RowSumView.cshtml:**

```
@model List<double>
<ul>
    @foreach(double item in Model) {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a workaround but I am wondering why my example is not working. Is there a better approach to pass multiple partial views?

Comment: It seems that it is related to holding a ViewData/Model object while rendering a PartialView (a single ViewData per an ActionResult). Possibly, this is expected behavior. I will try to check if there is a better solution. For now, you can use my suggested approach and always initialize each ActionResult/PartialViewResult with a new ViewData/Model instance.

Comment: This happens because of the [`PartialView`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs) helper of the controller that Maximum used to create each partial result. That helper will set the model in ViewData.Model where ViewData is a property in [the controller](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs). Calling twice `PartialResult` will override the ViewData.Model